# What is this extra column when I run 'ps' command?

Tags: zsh

I am running Babun with oh-my-zsh on a Windows machine.  When I run the `ps` command without any arguments I get the following output:

```
     PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY     UID    STIME COMMAND
     9660    7492    9660       9236  pty0    39904   Jun 12 /usr/bin/zsh
S    8072    9660    8072      12068  pty0    39904   Jun 13 /usr/bin/vim
    13296    9660   13296      12572  pty0    39904 14:29:08 /usr/bin/ps
     7480    7492    7492      19156  ?       39904   Jun 15 /usr/bin/mintty <defunct>
     7492       1    7492       7492  ?       39904   Jun 12 /usr/bin/mintty
```

The line that lists PID 8072 (`/usr/bin/vim`) has an "S" in its own column to the left of everything else.  The column does not have a header.

What does this "S" mean?

Comment: Please post text *as text,* not as a screenshot image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That column is for the **process state code** as discussed in the [ps man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ps1.html). `S` refers to an `interruptible sleep` which means that this process is waiting for an event to complete before resuming.

Open text editors(like Vim, Nano, Sublime Text, etc.) are commonly in the `S` state since they are waiting for additional input from the user to read or write to a file.

See [here](https://idea.popcount.org/2012-12-11-linux-process-states/) for a more detailed resource on process states. Although some of this information will vary since you're running a Windows machine. It might be best to only see this as a reference when in the command line and specifically with the **ps** command.

Comment: Excellent resources, thank you @baelx!  Babun's `man ps` responds with "No manual entry for ps", and `ps --help` displays very limited information - the links you provided are a big help.

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept my submission if you found it answered your question and in doing so you'll be participating in the SuperUser community :)